# Pyomo indexed constraint works with lambda-rule only

Tags: python, pyomo

I am puzzled by a pyomo error that I obtained when replacing a lambda-expression by a function.

Consider the following **working** example:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyomo
model = pyomo.ConcreteModel()
model.time_set = pyomo.Set(initialize=range(1, 3))
model.thermal_set = pyomo.Set(initialize=range(1, 3))
model.thermal_generation = pyomo.Var(model.time_set, model.thermal_set)
model.thermal_operation = pyomo.Var(model.time_set, model.thermal_set, bounds=(0, 1),)
model.thermal_reserve = pyomo.Var(
    model.time_set, model.thermal_set, domain=pyomo.NonNegativeReals
)
model.NGC = pyomo.Param(model.thermal_set, initialize={1: 0.6, 2: 0.3})
model.thermal_MSG = pyomo.Constraint(
    model.time_set,
    model.thermal_set,
    rule=lambda model, t, i: model.thermal_generation[t, i]
    + model.thermal_reserve[t, i]
    <= model.NGC[i] * model.thermal_operation[t, i],
)
```

**Replacing** the last line by

```
def thermal_NGC_constraint(model, t, i):
    thermal_NGC_constraint = (
        model.thermal_generation[t, i] + model.thermal_reserve[t, i]
        <= model.NGC[i] * model.thermal_operation[t, i],
    )
    return thermal_NGC_constraint


model.thermal_MSG = pyomo.Constraint(
     model.time_set, model.thermal_set, rule=thermal_NGC_constraint,
)
```

results in the error

```
Constraint 'thermal_MSG[1,1]' does not have a proper value. Found a tuple of length 1. Expecting a tuple of length 2 or 3:
    Equality:   (left, right)
    Inequality: (lower, expression, upper)
```

Rewriting other constraints like this worked. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a stray comma that is biting you.  Inside your function, you are assigning the expression to a malformed tuple unintentionally in this statement:

```
def thermal_NGC_constraint(model, t, i):
    thermal_NGC_constraint = (
        model.thermal_generation[t, i] + model.thermal_reserve[t, i]
        <= model.NGC[i] * model.thermal_operation[t, i],
    )
    return thermal_NGC_constraint
```

It is essentially saying this:

```
my_expression = (some vars <= other vars, ___)
```

which simplifies to:

```
my_expression = (<a pyomo expression>, )
```

which is a tuple type, not an expression.  I believe you *can* express expressions as tuples as the error kinda suggests, but that is not what you are trying to do here.  Remove the comma and all is well.  In fact, I've been bitten by this before and I recommend you do not put the expression in parens to prevent this from happening also.

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem and explains what happened. My project uses auto formatting in Black code style, which correctly added the comma in the lambda version. Yet, transfering it to the function changed its meaning and thus the error.